# graph plot API for ArangoDB pyArango

Tags: python, graph, arangodb, aql, pyarango

I am using ArangoDB community edition, I can query on a created graph in `AQL` and get results in JSON which is graphically visualized on ArangoDB web interface tool.

### `AQL` Query

```
FOR v,e,p IN 1..3 OUTBOUND 'germanCity/Hamburg' GRAPH 'routeplanner' 
OPTIONS{bfs :true} 
RETURN p
```

### JSON output

```
[
  {
    "edges": [
      {
        "_key": "6392826",
        "_id": "germanHighway/6392826",
        "_from": "germanCity/Hamburg",
        "_to": "germanCity/Cologne",
        "_rev": "_WmZ77pW--D",
        "distance": 500
      }
    ],
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "Hamburg",
        "_id": "germanCity/Hamburg",
        "_rev": "_WmZ77Z---_",
        "population": 1000000,
        "isCapital": false,
        "loc": [
          53.5653,
          10.0014
        ]
      },
      {
        "_key": "Cologne",
        "_id": "germanCity/Cologne",
        "_rev": "_WmZ77Y6--B",
        "population": 1000000,
        "isCapital": false,
        "loc": [
          50.9364,
          6.9528
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "edges": [
      {
        "_key": "6392840",
        "_id": "internationalHighway/6392840",
        "_from": "germanCity/Hamburg",
        "_to": "frenchCity/Paris",
        "_rev": "_WmZ77pa--_",
        "distance": 900
      }
    ],
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "Hamburg",
        "_id": "germanCity/Hamburg",
        "_rev": "_WmZ77Z---_",
        "population": 1000000,
        "isCapital": false,
        "loc": [
          53.5653,
          10.0014
        ]
      },
      {
        "_key": "Paris",
        "_id": "frenchCity/Paris",
        "_rev": "_WmZ77Z---D",
        "population": 4000000,
        "isCapital": true,
        "loc": [
          48.8567,
          2.3508
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "edges": [
      {
        "_key": "6392843",
        "_id": "internationalHighway/6392843",
        "_from": "germanCity/Hamburg",
        "_to": "frenchCity/Lyon",
        "_rev": "_WmZ77pa--B",
        "distance": 1300
      }
    ],
    "vertices": [
      {
        "_key": "Hamburg",
        "_id": "germanCity/Hamburg",
        "_rev": "_WmZ77Z---_",
        "population": 1000000,
        "isCapital": false,
        "loc": [
          53.5653,
          10.0014
        ]
      },
      {
        "_key": "Lyon",
        "_id": "frenchCity/Lyon",
        "_rev": "_WmZ77Z---B",
        "population": 80000,
        "isCapital": false,
        "loc": [
          45.76,
          4.84
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

### Equivalent Graph

[image: Graph Viewer]

As we can get visualized graph output in web interface I would like to display the same in Language<->ArangoDB. 
Language here can be driver language supported : Python, Java , C# etc.

I am using `pyArango` for interfacing with ArangoDB

I couldnt find an ArangoDB API for getting this graph visualization in JPG or matlibplot.

Is there any other way apart from using below two options?

1. Use `networkx.draw(networkx.graph)`
2. `matplotlib.pyplot`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need graph visualization then [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) library is for you. And if Python is OK then you only need a Python binding-library [graphviz](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/) (that utilizes [DOT language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_(graph_description_language)) representation internally.)

It is super easy to feed your graph JSON from Arango DB to graphviz for rendering.

You can customize it to your style, add labels, colors, reshape nodes and more.

Here is a simple example of your sample JSON:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

arango_graph = [
    {
        "edges": [
            {
                "_key": "6392826",
                "_id": "germanHighway/6392826",
                "_from": "germanCity/Hamburg",
                "_to": "germanCity/Cologne",
                "_rev": "_WmZ77pW--D",
                "distance": 500
            }
        ],
        "vertices": [
            {
                "_key": "Hamburg",
                "_id": "germanCity/Hamburg",
                "_rev": "_WmZ77Z---_",
                "population": 1000000,
                "isCapital": False,
                "loc": [
                    53.5653,
                    10.0014
                ]
            },
            {
                "_key": "Cologne",
                "_id": "germanCity/Cologne",
                "_rev": "_WmZ77Y6--B",
                "population": 1000000,
                "isCapital": False,
                "loc": [
                    50.9364,
                    6.9528
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "edges": [
            {
                "_key": "6392840",
                "_id": "internationalHighway/6392840",
                "_from": "germanCity/Hamburg",
                "_to": "frenchCity/Paris",
                "_rev": "_WmZ77pa--_",
                "distance": 900
            }
        ],
        "vertices": [
            {
                "_key": "Hamburg",
                "_id": "germanCity/Hamburg",
                "_rev": "_WmZ77Z---_",
                "population": 1000000,
                "isCapital": False,
                "loc": [
                    53.5653,
                    10.0014
                ]
            },
            {
                "_key": "Paris",
                "_id": "frenchCity/Paris",
                "_rev": "_WmZ77Z---D",
                "population": 4000000,
                "isCapital": True,
                "loc": [
                    48.8567,
                    2.3508
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "edges": [
            {
                "_key": "6392843",
                "_id": "internationalHighway/6392843",
                "_from": "germanCity/Hamburg",
                "_to": "frenchCity/Lyon",
                "_rev": "_WmZ77pa--B",
                "distance": 1300
            }
        ],
        "vertices": [
            {
                "_key": "Hamburg",
                "_id": "germanCity/Hamburg",
                "_rev": "_WmZ77Z---_",
                "population": 1000000,
                "isCapital": False,
                "loc": [
                    53.5653,
                    10.0014
                ]
            },
            {
                "_key": "Lyon",
                "_id": "frenchCity/Lyon",
                "_rev": "_WmZ77Z---B",
                "population": 80000,
                "isCapital": False,
                "loc": [
                    45.76,
                    4.84
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

graph_name = 'amazing'

g = Digraph(graph_name, filename=graph_name, format='jpeg', engine='neato')
g.attr(scale='2', label='Look at my graph my graph is amazing!', fontsize='18')
g.attr('node', shape='circle', fixedsize='true', width='1')

for item in arango_graph:
    for vertex in item['vertices']:
        g.node(vertex['_id'], label=vertex['_key'])
    for edge in item['edges']:
        g.edge(edge['_from'], edge['_to'], label=str(edge['distance']))

# Render to file into some directory
g.render(directory='/tmp/', filename=graph_name)
# Or just show rendered file using system default program
g.view()
```

Just 3 code lines for customization and 5 more to feed the graph visualization renderer. And please note that Arango Web UI does not render all of the edges between the same pair of nodes while graphviz does and you can style each differently.

You will need to install `graphviz` library and Python bindings

**Step #1: Install library**

*Assuming your machine is Ubuntu:*

```
sudo apt install graphviz
```

**Step #2: Get Python bindings**

```
pipenv install graphviz
```

*If you not yet using [Pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) you can install with good old [Pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)):*

```
pip install graphviz
```

**Step #3: Run sample and enjoy**

[image: Amazing graph, rendered in JPEG]